# About Radio Button in ListView.builder() flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on Radio Button in a ListView.builder() but when I select any of the radio button it is selecting each and every radio button rather than selected one.

My code is given below:

```
ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 67,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return _buildCheckListItems(index);
                    }),


Widget _buildCheckListItems(int index) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Seat Belts',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 200,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Radio(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  changeValue(val);
                },
              ),
              Radio(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  changeValue(val);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


changeValue(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio = val;
    });
  }
```

The output result of above code is as follow:

[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEPGl.png)

Comment: have you found this issue i also face same issue and answer below i dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that you are using a same `groupValue: selectedRadio,` Each radio button group must have different `groupValue` otherwise it will shared the same change.

If you do not want to specify name for each radio button group you can just create a new .dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class buildCheckListItems extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  buildCheckListItems(this.index); //I don't know what is this index for but I will put it in anyway
  @override
  _buildCheckListItemsState createState() => _buildCheckListItemsState();
}

class _buildCheckListItemsState extends State<buildCheckListItems> {
  int selectedRadio = -1;

  changeValue(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        ...
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and now everything should be working just fine.

Comment: how can we retrieve data selected using above process

Comment: Sorry for late reply, actually we should add pass `onChanged` prop and pass `changeValue()` function to it.